# Relative path in webBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I made a form in Visual Studio (Window Forms) and used a webbrowser from the toolbox.

I want to open in the webbrowser a web page from the local drive. In the properties, in the URL box if I write the absolute path (eg c:\xwelcome.html) it works, but how can I use a relative path (eg the page is in my resources folder) ?
my path :C:\Users\CCJ\source\repos\myapp\Resources\Welcome\welcome.html
I try .\welcome.html but it didn't work. Any idea??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't include  "c:\" which goes to root folder.  What I normally do is to open the csproj file with notepad and replace the folder name that starts with "c:\" and put in a relative path.

Comment: Please edit the formatting of the question and highlight the areas with code as code in the text editor when you write the questions. it will make it easier for us to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\CCJ\source\repos\myapp\Resources\Welcome");
        this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/welcome.html", dir.FullName));
```